# Como desligar um evento em JS com responsividade?

Tags: javascript, layout-responsivo, eventos-do-mouse

Estou tendo problemas para deixar meu site responsivo. Ao usuário passar o mouse em cima do cabeçalho em PCs, o cabeçalho deve mudar de cor. Mas queria desabilitar esse evento em dispositivos móveis.

Código JS:

```
cabecalho.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(150, 150, 150)";
}) 

cabecalho.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
})
```

Como posso desabilitar isso?

Comment: talvez isso: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56581950/6797930 tem que testar

Comment: Alguém pode testar `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(d=>{ console.log(d)});` aqui o motor é touchscreen detecta como video input device.

Comment: Você pode verificar os valores de: ```window.screen.width```, ```window.screen.height```, exemplo: ```if (window.screen.width >= 1024)```

Comment: esse simples função funciona: `window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
      const isMobile = !window.matchMedia('only screen and (min-width: 768px)').matches;
      console.log(isMobile);
    });`

Comment: @novic, não funciona no ipad a resolução é 2224 x 1668 px

Comment: @AugustoVasques funcionou comigo sim!

Comment: é só ajustar o tamanho @AugustoVasques eu coloquei um exemplo e um link

Answer (score -2):

Pra saber se está no mobile, você pode validar pelo `window.screen.width`.
E para tirar o efeito, você precisa criar um `removeEventListener(/*...*/)`

Ficaria algo tipo:

```
var div = document.getElementById('div');
var listener = function (event) {
  /* faça alguma coisa... */
};
div.addEventListener('click', listener, false);
if(window.screen.width < 1024) { // aqui você define o tamanho pra mobile
    div.removeEventListener('click', listener, false);
}
```